# Delete the blank area under the container in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to delete the blank area under the container in bootstrap.
How can I do that?

[image]

```css
.p {
  color: white;
}

.box_switch {
  position: relative;
  background: #1E3E75;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 0px calc(50% - 50vw) 15px;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mx-auto text-center">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="box_switch">
        <p class="p">PPPPPPPPPPP</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] and show what expected output should be. Right now your "I do not need this white area" is in the blue area

Comment: He/she tagged `bootstrap-4`.

Comment: Also look here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/reboot/

Answer (score 0):

Browsers apply a default stylesheet to HTML documents. This default contains a [margin for the `<body>` element](https://browserdefaultstyles.com/#body). Add

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

to your stylesheet and the white area vanishes.